# constexpr expression and variable lifetime, an example where g++ and clang disagree

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

Consider the simple C++11 code:

```
template<int N>
struct Foo {};

template <int N>
constexpr int size(const Foo<N>&) { return N; }

template <int N>
void use_size(const Foo<N>& foo) { constexpr int n = size(foo); }

int main()
{
    Foo<5> foo;

    constexpr int x = size(foo);  // works with gcc and clang
                                  // _but_
    use_size(foo);                // the same statement in the use_size() 
                                  // function _only_ works for gcc
}
```

I can successfuly compile it with `g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp`

however if I use clang++, `clang++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp` I get

```
foo.cpp:15:28: error: constexpr variable 'n' must be initialized by a constant expression
void use_size(const Foo<N>& foo) { constexpr int n = size(foo); }
                                                     ~~~~~^~~~
foo.cpp:23:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'use_size<5>' requested here
    use_size(foo);                // the same statement in the use_size() 
    ^
1 error generated.
```

(nb: compiler versions. I have checked the previous statement with g++ version 5.3.1 and 7.2.1 and with clang++ version 3.6.2 and 5.0.0)

**My question:** which of g++ or clang is right? What is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My interpretation is that **clang++ is right** and **g++ is too permissive**.

We can find a close example ([expr.const] section, page 126) in the standard https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard (draft can be downloaded, [attention big PDF!](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4700.pdf) ).

```
constexpr int g(int k) { 
    constexpr int x = incr(k); 

    return x; 
}
```

where it is explained that:

> error: incr(k) is not a core constant expression because 
>   lifetime of k began outside the expression incr(k)

This is exactly what is happening in the `use_size()` function with the `foo` argument, even if the `size()` function **only** use the `N` template parameter.

```
template <int N>
constexpr int size(const Foo<N>&) { return N; }

template <int N>
void use_size(const Foo<N>& foo) { constexpr int n = size(foo); }
```

Comment: I believe this answer to be correct. To add support, Clang and MSVC accept the code when the lifetime of the argument to `size` and `use_size` begin within the scope of the function: [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/As94wb0ojrETqhon)

Comment: @AndyG I disagree, as the quoted non-normative example is just demonstrating the rule [expr.const] ¶2.7.4 "an expression `e` is a _core constant expression_ unless ... [it] would evaluate... an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless... [it] refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`". The example is an error because `incr(k)` involves an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (because it increments the lvalue) whereas `size(foo)` does not (because it merely binds an lvalue reference to the lvalue). [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/g9znfUdKJjhQiIC8)

Comment: @Oktalist: Thanks for the response. I was more thinking along the lines of the part in [expr.const] that says "An expression e is a core constant expression unless... [it's] an id-expression that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a
preceding initialization and either
it is initialized with a constant expression or,
 its lifetime began within the evaluation of e;" OPs example deals with reference binding and is an error because the lifetime of the reference was not initialized with a constant expression or begin with the evaluation of e

Comment: @AndyG Thanks, I missed that. Disagreement withdrawn.

Answer (score 3):

I was expecting Clang to be wrong in this case. It should evaluate your function call as being a constant expression, simply because you use only the template parameter, and not the object itself. Since you don't use the object in your `constexpr` function, there should be nothing prohibit compile time evaluation.

However, there's a rule in the standard that says object that began their lifetime preceding the constant expression such as a reference is not useable as constexpr.

There is a simple fix in that case. I think it didn't like the reference:

```
template <int N> // pass by value, clang is happy
void use_size(Foo<N> foo) { constexpr int n = size(foo); }
```

Here's a [live example](https://godbolt.org/g/xYtDXm)

Alternatively, you can also copy your foo object and use that local object:

```
template <int N>
void use_size(const Foo<N>& foo) {
    auto f = foo;
    constexpr int n = size(f);
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/g/MT9nNa)

Comment: That was my first thought. It is true that the compiler has everything it needs to know the value of n at compile time. However, I think that the standard prohibits this for the reason I provided in my "interpretation".

Comment: Yeah, reading the rules more closely, I think you're right. References don`t play really well with constexpr in certain cases it seems